Split string with parentheses, sub-parentheses and space
In Python, I have the following string:
string_example = '11 31 (31 573) ((11 573)<(31 573 [1 0 0])<(11 31))'
I would like to extract a list by splitting the string using spaces and "()" as delimiters, without splitting the sub-parentheses. The desired list is:
list_split=['11', '31', '(31 573)', '((11 573)<(31 573 [1 0 0])<(11 31))']

You can do this with pyparsing. Defining a grammar can be relatively simpler to maintain than manually parsing the string.
import pyparsing as pp

# Define a grammar
integer = pp.Word(pp.nums).setResultsName("integer")
nested_expr = pp.nestedExpr("(", ")").setResultsName("composite")
expr = integer | nested_expr

parsed_list = expr.searchString('11 31 (31 573) ((11 573)<(31 573 [1 0 0])<(11 31))')

def reconstruct(item):
    if isinstance(item, str):
        return item
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        return '(' + ' '.join([reconstruct(x) for x in item]) + ')'
    elif item.get_name() == 'integer':
        return str(item[0])
    elif item.get_name() == 'composite':
        return '(' + ' '.join([reconstruct(x) for x in item[0].asList()]) + ')'

list_split = [reconstruct(item) for item in parsed_list]
print(list_split)

Note that the resulting strings may have different whitespace from what you started with. Also note that you do need to actually parse the string inside the parenthesis as well to know where it closes.
Technically, you could also do this with regular expressions, but not with the built-in re module, which does not support lists of match groups. Your requirement is complex enough that you're pushing at the limits of what regular expressions are designed for.

Thank you very much! Removing some whitespace is also helpful for what I need.

Thoughts：Split the string based on either spaces or parentheses, and if there are multiple parentheses, match the same number of closing parentheses to end the split.
def custom_split(string):
    result = []
    current = ""
    count = 0
    for char in string:
        if char == ' ' and count == 0:
            if current:
                result.append(current)
            current = ""
        elif char == '(':
            count += 1
            current += char
        elif char == ')' and count > 0:
            count -= 1
            current += char
            if count == 0:
                result.append(current)
                current = ""
        else:
            current += char
    
    if current:
        result.append(current)
    
    return result

string_example = '11 31 (31 573) ((11 573)<(31 573 [1 0 0])<(11 31))'
list_split = custom_split(string_example)
print(list_split)

This function iterates through the input string character by character, splitting based on spaces or parentheses. When encountering a left parenthesis, the counter increases, and when encountering a right parenthesis, the counter decreases. The current split unit ends and is added to the result list only when the counter reaches zero.

Similar to the other answer, but a bit more concise and a bit less "ChatGPT", avoiding some repetition:
def p_split(s: str) -> list[str]:
    buffer = ''
    depth = 0
    for ch in s:
        # split over whitespace, but include whitespace inside parentheses
        if ch in ' \t\n\r\f\v' and depth == 0:
            if buffer:
                yield buffer
                buffer = ''
        else:
            buffer += ch
        # track how many parentheses are open
        if ch == '(':
            depth += 1
        # note that there can't be a negative depth
        if ch == ')' and depth:
            depth -= 1
    # yield what remains, if any, in case of unclosed parentheses
    if buffer:
        yield buffer


string_example = '11 31 (31 573) ((11 573)<(31 573 [1 0 0])<(11 31))'
print(list(p_split(string_example)))

Note that there's some aspects you might not like here, which is a matter of taste. The solution uses the 'truthiness' of strings to determine if the string is empty. And it accepts any whitespace as a separator where you may just need the space. Both are easily adjusted. The solution also creates a generator instead of returning a list, which I prefer because it's more flexible, but of course you can just add to a list instead of yielding values.
